# How to configure this correctly

Tags: php

I want this so it logs errors, It works but I`

```
 <?php  
 if(!empty($err))  {
   echo "<div class=\"msg\">";
  foreach ($err as $e) {
    echo "* $e <br>";
    }
  echo "</div>";    
   }
 ?>
```

I want to add this to that

```
    <div class="alert alert-app-level alert-danger">
      <div class="alert-item">
    <div class="alert-text">
        LOGIN ERROR TEXT HERE
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can check basic PHP embedding in HTML, https://www.ntchosting.com/encyclopedia/scripting-and-programming/php/php-in/

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?php
$error = array("test1","test2");
$html = "";
if($error) {
    $html .= '<div class="alert alert-app-level alert-danger">
              <div class="alert-item">
              <div class="alert-text">';
    foreach ($error as $e) {
        $html .= "<p>".$e."</p>";
    }
    $html .= '</div>
              </div>
              </div>';
echo $html;
}
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Embed php in html and encapsulate each error message in a `div` tag for further CSS-customization (no need for `<br>` anymore):

```
<div class="alert alert-app-level alert-danger">
    <div class="alert-item">
        <div class="alert-text">
            <?php
            if (!empty($err)) {
                ?>
                <div class="msg">
                    <?php
                    foreach ($err as $e) {
                        ?>
                        <div class="error">* <?php echo $e; ?></div>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```